# spawning object on the ground in terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a randomly spawn animal script but my animals spawning inside the hill and my terrain has a lot of hill. How do i make the animals spawn always on the ground.

Note: Normally my terrains y axis value is 0.

Here is my code.

```
IEnumerator spawnenemiesatposition1()
{
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
while (cond1)
{
    Vector3 position1 = new Vector3(Random.Range(5, 195), 1, Random.Range(5, 495));
    Instantiate(Deer, position1, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0));
    deernum1++;
    if (deernum1 > 5)
    {
        cond1 = false;
    }

}
```

[Example of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6COK.jpg)

How could i make the animals spawn always on the ground.

Comment: Maybe spawn them way above the terrain, then cast a ray downwards, and move them to wherever the raycast hits.

Comment: i tried this but didn't work is it correct?         "if(Physics.Raycast(Deer.transform.position,          -Vector3.up, out RaycastHit thehit))"       if (thehitT.transform.gameObject.CompareTag("Map"))
                    {
                        Deer.transform.position = thehit.point;
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Terrain.SampleHeight`.

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html).

Basically, given your world position, it returns you the height of the terrain in that position.